# Add additional labels in highcharts

Tags: python, highcharts

The following image is the boxplot visualization. As there are differently coloured labels, I wanted to add additional data in the legend.
[image]
This is the code for my boxplot labels in Python.

```
series = [{
    'name': 'Percentile Values',
    'data': data
},{
    'name': 'Atoms',
    'type':'scatter',
    'keys': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
    'data': obss,
    'tooltip': {
        'pointFormat': 'Index: {point.z}, Suspicion Score: {point.y}'
    },
    'zones': [{
            'value': THRES,
          'color': 'black'
        }, {'value': 1.0,
            'color': 'red'
        }]
    }]
```

How do I add additional items in the legend?

Comment: I think that one idea is to add new series with your colours, another is to make custom label using Renderer.label(): http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.label

Comment: If you want an actual legend entry, the most logical approach is to make each color its own series.